# Laptop shuts down shortly after boot up

Tags: boot, laptop, power-supply, shutdown

I have an Acer Aspire laptop running Windows 10, and after boot up, it just turns off (as if the power was cut). This happens regardless of power supply (plugged in, battery in or out, power disconnected also).

I've tried changing the boot settings in the F2 menu, I cannot access the F8 menu (regardless of how fast I mash the F8 button on boot), and it made no difference.

If I try to log in, it shuts down quicker than if I leave it sit.

I believe it could be something to do with the hardware, but at this point I'm not sure. I haven't attempted a reinstall yet.

Comment: Too many possibilities - it might be simpler to use a repair-shop.

Comment: Could be bad power supply, bad battery, or overheating.  Need to do some physical diagnostics to pick one.